# run unittests from a command prompt

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I have created python files and unittests but I do not understand how can i run all the tests in one go from command prompt.

file structure

```
- py
  - __init__.py
  - file1.py
  - file2.py
- tests
  __init__.py
  - test_file1.py
  - test_file2.py
```

Please let me know the same.
when i try to run tests using nosetests, it says me

```
no module name file1
no module name file2
```

Comment: please post full error traceback.

Answer (score 3):

Below is a snip from Nose's documentation (since you've tagged `nose`)

> **nose collects tests automatically from python source files, directories and packages found in its working directory (which defaults to the current working directory).** Any python source file, directory or package that matches the testMatch regular expression (by default: `(?:\b|_)[Tt]est` will be collected as a test (or source for collection of tests). In addition, all other packages found in the working directory will be examined for python source files or directories that match testMatch. Package discovery descends all the way down the tree, so package.tests and package.sub.tests and package.sub.sub2.tests will all be collected.

Emphasis mine.

You can simply run all the test cases from the root directory of your project:

```
$ cd /path/to/your/project
$ nosetests
```

Comment: I did the same but it says "no module named test1" and "no module named test2"

Comment: @sam Try removing the `__init__.py` from the tests directory

Comment: I do not see any `test1` or `test2` in your directory structure. Are you sure it is not a bug within your own code? Edit your question and update it with the full traceback.

Comment: sorry it says "no module named file1" and "no module named file2"

Comment: I hope you are doing `from py.file1 import some_object` (assuming `py/__init__.py` is not doing anything significant). Either way, please post 1) the error traceback, 2) A really concise source module, 3) a really concise test module that reproduces the problem. That is the only way we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

For simple discovery, you can use the built-in command-line functionality of the `unittest` module

```
$ cd /path/to/your/project/tests
$ python -m unittest discover
```

Or, if your `tests` directory has an `__init__.py`, you can do

```
$ cd /path/to/your/project
$ python -m unittest discover -s ./tests
```

If you absolutely *must* use python 2.6, the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#module-unittest) say you can install `unittest2`, which is a backport of the new features added in python 2.7.  You invoke it slightly differently

```
$ unit2 discover
```

Also, if you haven't already gone too far down the `unittest` testing rabbit hole, I would recommend checking out [`pytest`](http://pytest.org/latest/).  It requires a lot less boilerplate when writing tests and allows you to just use the built-in `assert`.  It also comes with some other cool features like *fixtures* and *parameterized test functions* that also allow you to reduce the amount of code in your unittests.

Comment: I am using python 2.6.6. it says no module named discover

Comment: `discover` requires Py2.7+ IIRC. @Brendan: OP has tagged `nosetests` not `pytest`

Comment: @SuperSaiyan Yeah, didn't even realize it was a new feature.  It's been so long since I've seen a pre-2.7 system.  The `pytest` plug was just an added bonus in addition to the answer.  I switched to `pytest` a few years ago and feel it's my duty to save as many people as possible from having to write `unittest.TestCase` and `self.assertNotEqual` monstrousities.